# Can an Indian citizen studying in Germany travel to India through Paris airport?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, europe, germany, german-residents

I am an Indian citizen with valid German student long term resident visa. Can I travel to India and come back through Paris airport? Is there a chance of being denied to board? Prices are cheaper from Paris than from a german airport.

Edit: Sorry that my English is not clear. Yes, I meant I plan to travel to Paris by train and take Paris-Mumbai flight and return to Paris via Mumbai-Paris return flight and come back to Germany via train.

Comment: @DavidRicherby this question doesn't seem to be about transit in the senses of the word most commonly used in the Schengen area.  The intention seems to be to travel to Paris by land ("Prices are cheaper from Paris").  An answer to this question can certainly be deduced from the 1100-word accepted answer to the proposed duplicate, but that seems like rather much to ask.

Comment: @phoog Yes, perhaps it wasn't a good suggestion of duplicate. On the other hand, we do have a lot of questions about coming in and out of Schengen so it seems likely that this is a duplicate of one of them. We certainly have a question about whether you have to enter Schengen in the country that granted your visa (you don't) and the whole point of Schengen is that you can move freely within it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby that is certainly true.  There does seem to be a good deal of misunderstanding about the terms of D visas, however, which is not helped by the fact that in the "valid for" entry they mention only the country of issue.  This leaves open reasonable (but mistaken) interpretations such as that someone with such a visa issued by Germany might be forbidden to travel to France, or permitted to travel there but not to enter or exit the Schengen area there.  Coupled with the possible misunderstandings of immigration and customs controls for internal connecting flights, it's rather messy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Germany and France are both in the Schengen area. If you have a long-stay visa (or residence permit) that lets you travel to Germany, you can also use that visa to enter or leave the Schengen area in Paris on your way to/from Germany.

In general such a visa also lets you visit the other Schengen countries on the same conditions as visa-free nationals.

Comment: The question is about leaving the Schengen area, while this answer is about entering it.

Comment: @phoog "Can I travel to India and come back through Paris airport?" could be interpreted as meaning "Can I travel to India via whatever route, and then return via Paris?" or "Can I travel to India via Paris and then return via Paris?" but both interpretations do require entering Schengen in Paris.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the question title, however, is just "Can an Indian citizen studying in Germany travel to India through Paris airport?"